# Material-UI Box Component Import Order and Style Tag Generation

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, jss

I'm using the Material-UI (Mui) Box component to save time. It works great most of the time, but I sometimes run into issues when the styling clashes with the default styling of other Mui components. For example, I'm using the Box component to override the default padding-right of the Mui Toolbar (see picture below).

[image: Navbar component utilizing Box component]

The problem and my question lie in the way the style tags are generated from this code. The style tags generated by this Box component are being overridden by the style tags generated by the Toolbar component (see picture below).

[image: DevTools showing styles]

Additionally, when I inspect these style tags the MuiBox tags are definitely inserted before the majority of the other style tags and they seem to be empty. (see pictures below).

[image: DevTools showing the style tags.]

I've read the docs over and over, and tried many things. The most promising thing I could find was in the documentation for the Box component:

> ⚠️ The CSS specificity relies on the import order. If you want the guarantee that the wrapped component's style will be overridden, you need to import the Box last.
>   I tried this but still have had no success (see image below).

[image]

I know there are several ways to get around this (e.g., makeStyles, withStyles, inline styles, !important), but these strategies make using the Box component somewhat pointless in many situations. So my question is how do I make the MuiBox style tags have the highest priority (inserted last) and why are they empty when I look at them in DevTools?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19048

Comment: As far as determining why the `Box` styles aren't winning, please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @c_rueschenberg have you been able to resolve this issue with box styles not having the highest priority? I have the same problem

Comment: @RyanCogswell here is the example https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-feather-yji6s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @jbojcic I wasn't able to resolve it, so I have been refraining from using the Box component with the clone prop. In many situations you can either use the Box as a direct parent or direct child of whatever component you would be trying to clone to get the job done. In situations I can't, I just end up creating a new class and adding the class to the element I wanted to clone.